# Blueimp jQuery File Upload plugin - Over Quota Error when clicking 'Start Upload'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, blueimp

I'm using Blueimp's jQuery file upload plugin, and have not been able to get it to work. I'm using it on this [site](http://grk.co/test2/upload.html). I seem to be able to add files okay, but when I click 'start upload', it takes me to a page where it says "Error. Over Quota. This application is temporarily over its serving quota. Please try again later." Has anyone seen this before?

Here is my HTML:

```
<form id="fileupload" action="//grk.co/test2/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <!-- Redirect browsers with JavaScript disabled to the origin page -->
        <noscript><input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://grk.co/test2/"></noscript>
        <!-- The fileupload-buttonbar contains buttons to add/delete files and start/cancel the upload -->
        <div class="row fileupload-buttonbar">
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
                <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                    <span>Add files...</span>
                    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
                </span>
                <button type="submit" class="tiny success start">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload"></i>
                    <span>Start upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="reset" class="tiny secondary cancel">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle"></i>
                    <span>Cancel upload</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="tiny alert delete">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    <span>Delete</span>
                </button>
                <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
                <!-- The loading indicator is shown during file processing -->
                <span class="fileupload-loading"></span>
            </div>
            <!-- The global progress information -->
            <div class="col-lg-5 fileupload-progress fade">
                <!-- The global progress bar -->
                <div class="progress progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%;"></div>
                </div>
                <!-- The extended global progress information -->
                <div class="progress-extended">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- The table listing the files available for upload/download -->
        <table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files"></tbody></table>
    </form>
```

And my JS:

```
<script>
/*jslint unparam: true */
/*global window, $ */
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = window.location.hostname === '91.208.99.4' ?
                '//grk.co/test2/' : 'server/php/';
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        }
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
</script>
```

If anyone can spot anything wrong, I would greatly appreciate it. I am pretty new with jQuery so I am most definitely missing something.

If any more information is needed, please let me know.

Comment: Updates the URLs but, now just redirects to index.html instead of going to the over quota page. I am not sure what URL I should be using instead. Clearly I don't know what I'm doing. Someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your upload processing script on the server? Currently (on the sample page you linked) uploaded files are being sent to http://grk.co/test2/server/php/. I'm guessing this isn't what you want since /server/php/ is just the default supplied with the blueimp package. You need to point to your own upload handling script.

Comment: My UploadHandler.php is located in server/php/. I've pointed to it correctly now in the js, but do you know where I change the url to point to the folder I want the uploaded files to go into? Also, the progress bar still does nothing. Uploaded files ARE going into a folder, but not the one I want.

Comment: Where the uploaded files are saved will be controlled by the code in UploadHandler.php. Look for move_uploaded_file(foo,bar). Bar will be where the files are moved. Progress bars are harder for me to debug. But do you need the progressall: function (e, data) {}? I would try taking that out (along with the comma following the done: function {}) and see what happens.